# Maven: Extract dependency resources before test

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a multimodule Maven project. One subproject hosts XSL/XML resource files. The other project hosts Java code that needs to use these files in its unit tests.

In the dependency's jar, the resources lie in the folder `xml-resources`.

I found this [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/using-dependencies-sources.html) and tried to change it for my needs:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>resource-dependencies</id>
      <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>xml-resources</classifier>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/xml-resources</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This doesn't do anything when I run the process-test-resources phase. Am am sure that there are some errors in there - I do not see where I can specify the dependency the resources should be taken from, and `<classifier>` does not seem to actually specify the source where the resources should be copied from.

I'm lost here, can somebody tell me how to do this right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>resource-dependencies</id>
      <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <includeArtifactIds>my-artifact-id</includeArtifactIds>
        <includes>foobar.txt, loremipsum.xml</includes>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/xml-resources</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Have a look at the [unpack-dependencies parameters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) for detailed explanation or further information.

Comment: The outputDirectory folder in this case should be ../test-classes/.. instead of ../classes/....

Comment: @khmarbaise valid objection - maybe even better `${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/xml-resources` (see [Super POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM))

Comment: Thanks for this, copying works now. The files lie in `target/test-classes/xml-resources`. However, I'm not able to load them in my test code via `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xml-resources/file.xml")`. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Ah forget it, that was my IDE's fault.