# Include files from a JAR in a dependent project

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'd like to synchronize log4j and logback config files across multiple projects. I have one project (Project A) that contains the log4j and logback dependencies, along with the config files.

Project A

- src/test/resources

  - log4j2.xml
  - logback-test.xml

Project B has a dependency on Project A. I would like to include the log config files in Project A's JAR and have them automatically put in a specific target folder in Project B when resolving Maven dependencies for Project B.

I have tried `maven-jar-plugin` in Project A but it doesn't seem to work for my purpose.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>src/test/resources/log4j2.xml</include>
            <include>src/test/resources/logback-test.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

While Eugene's answer was accepted, I needed to add a `<resources>` entry so the log config files would be included in the packaged JAR.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>log4j2.xml</include>
                <include>logback-test.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Executing `mvn clean compile assembly:single deploy` from Project A created and deployed the JAR with the log files included.

```
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.7.0:bundle (default) @ project-a ---
[INFO] Writing META-INF/maven/remote-resources.xml descriptor with 2 entries
```

Executing `mvn clean compile` from Project B copied the files into the output directory

```
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.7.0:process (default) @ project-b ---
[INFO] Preparing remote bundle com.my.projects:project-a:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Copying 2 resources from 1 bundle.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Apache Maven Remote Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/)

> This plugin is used to retrieve JARs of resources from remote
> repositories, process those resources, and incorporate them into JARs
> you build with Maven.
>
> A very common use-case is the need to package certain resources in a
> consistent way across your organization. For example at Apache, it is
> required that every JAR produced contains a copy of the Apache license
> and a notice file that references all used software in a given project

1. Define in Project A which resources you want to share or better create separate project for shared resources

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bundle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <resourcesDirectory>src/test/resources/</resourcesDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>log4j2.xml</include>
                        <include>logback-test.xml</include>
                      </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Maven will create [resources bundle file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/remote-resources.html) for sharing resources
`${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/maven/remote-resources.xml`

```xml
<remoteResourcesBundle xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/remote-resources/1.1.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/remote-resources-1.1.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/remote-resources/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <remoteResources>
    <remoteResource>log4j2.xml</remoteResource>
    <remoteResource>logback-test.xml</remoteResource>
  </remoteResources>
  <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
</remoteResourcesBundle>
```

See [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/bundle-mojo.html)

2. Configure other modules to use the shared resources

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>[your output directory]</outputDirectory>
                    <resourceBundles>
                        <!--The resource bundles that will be retrieved and processed. For example: org.test:shared-resources:${project.version}-->
                        <resourceBundle>groupId:artifactId:version[:type[:classifier]]</resourceBundle> 
                    </resourceBundles>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

See [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/process-mojo.html)

*Alternative solution:*

[Apache Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html)  It can copy and/or unpack artifacts from local or remote repositories to a specified location.

It was described there [Maven: Extract dependency resources before test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532274/maven-extract-dependency-resources-before-test)
and there [Use a dependency's resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292283/use-a-dependencys-resources)

**UPDATE:**

Example how to add resources:

```xml
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder 1 here]</directory>
     </resource>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder 2 here]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

See [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Eugene! I have accepted it! I was able to setup the maven-remote-resources-plugin in both projects and got the log config files synced from Project A to Project B! One update I have added to my original question: I needed to add <resources> to Project A's POM. Feel free to add it to your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Added example specifying resource directories. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please don't put logging configuration files into JARs, if someone depends on your JAR, your configuration may overwrite theirs. That depends on which JAR is loaded first

If you want, like this. And package them into JAR

- src/main/resources

  - log4j2.xml
  - logback.xml

Comment: Thanks for your feedback xiaobo9! I do agree there could be a contention problem, but we have agreed to only keep the log files in Project A. Otherwise, we would of had to find another solution.